# What's wrong in the below react redux code snippets?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have created react app and try to run after adding simple redux stuffs as below.
Initial state value and updated state value(after button click) not appearing in the screen.
No error thrown in the console.

Expected result should be display the initial Message from store as "Please subscribe".
After clicking subscribe button, the text should be change into "Thanks for Subscribing!".

## index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './Reducer';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const store = createStore(reducer);
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

## Reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    message: "Please subscribe!"
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log(action);
    const newState = { ...state };

    if (action.type === "PRINT_ITEM") {
        newState.message = "Thanks for subscribing!"
    };

    return newState;
}

export default reducer;
```

## App.js

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { NewComp } from './NewComp';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <NewComp />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

## NewComp.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class NewComp extends Component {

    styles = {
        fontStyle: 'italic',
        color: 'purple'
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h3 style={this.styles}>{this.props.msg}</h3>
                <button onClick={this.props.ButtonChange}>Subscribe</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state); //Not get fired
    return {
        msg: state.message
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps  = (dispatch) => {
    console.log(dispatch); //Not get fired
    return {
        ButtonChange: () => dispatch({ type: "PRINT_ITEM" })
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewComp);
```

Answer (score 2):

In `App.js`, you're importing the *named* export from `NewComp`, which is not the Redux-connected version. Instead, import the *default* export, which is Redux-connected:

```js
import NewComp from './NewComp';
```